# Cannot set character "[" in an input in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have something like this:

```
    titleBox = driver.find_element_by_id("titleInput")
    title = "[some text to input]"
    titleBox.send_keys(title)
```

The input fills well all text except "[" character.

Comment: use `title = "\[some text to input\]"`

Comment: @Laif I had already tried to escape the character

Comment: If you replace `[` with another character does it show up? i.e. does only the first character not show up or specifically `[`?

Comment: just [ other character goes well, even ]

Comment: If you try to type the `[` in manually, does it work?

Comment: yes i can write the char in the same input manually, i`ve been trying to concatenate the character as a ascii char and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
title = """[some text to input]"""
```

or else

```
title = r"[some text to input]"
```